# Special symbols in Spring request`s parameters

Tags: java, spring

I have

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getTaxiByPhone",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getTaxiByPhone(@RequestParam ("phone") String phone){
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<taxiList.size();i++){
        if ((taxiList.get(i).getPhone()).equals(phone)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return "found "+count;
}
@RequestMapping(value ="/getTaxiPhone",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getAllTaxi(@RequestParam ("id") int id){
    return taxiList.get(id).getPhone();
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/getAllTaxi",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Taxi> getAllTaxi(){
    return taxiList;
}
```

For example `getTaxi?id=2` returned `{"taxi_city_id":[55000001,67000001],"taxi_id":1113,"taxi_name":"zxcv","taxi_phon‌​e":"+73812999997"}` , but if you try `getTaxiByPhone?phone=+73812999997` you will not find any objects, because if you try return phone parameter with count (`return "found "+count+" for phone"+ phone;`), you will see `found 0 for phone 73812999997`. This means that sign '+' lost when spring parse url.

Comment: Just to note, are you performing the request against an URL ending with `getTaxiPhone?id=<id>` right?

Comment: yes, for example if i do /getTaxiPhone?id=2 i get string +73812999997, but if do /getTaxiByPhone?phone=+73812999997 i can`t find objects

Comment: And isn't +73812999997 the phone number associated to taxi with id 2?

Comment: getTaxi?id=2 return {"taxi_city_id":[55000001,67000001],"taxi_id":1113,"taxi_name":"zxcv","taxi_phone":"+73812999997"}

Comment: I guess you're being confused by the fact you're searching by the id of the taxi but want to add another functionality to search for phone number, which isn't currently covered by your code.

Comment: What about comparing strings via `equals()`? Does that ring a bell? :)

Comment: `if ((taxiList.get(i).getPhone())==phone)`  Don't compare `String`s with `==`, you must use the `equals()` method.

Comment: i didn`t understand your opinion, because i just compare object`s field with parameter "phone" and there is no specific code or functional(sorry for my bad english). But i founded some,i try return return "found "+count+"for phone" + phone; and get "found 0 for phone 73812999997". plus is missing. did you know why?

Comment: Once again, `String` comparisons should be done with the `equals()` method, not with `==`, which compares references. Your code should be `if (taxiList.get(i).getPhone().equals(phone))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be an issue with special characters, because you pass the telephone number with a '+' in your request. The + sign in URL get request is used to represent a space you should escape it, probably with

```
%2B
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Take that _more info here_ and copy the relevant bits to your answer.

Comment: No, Spring already handles that, otherwise countless people would already have stopped using it in real world apps around the world.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Done. I'm still afraid of being accused of stealing someone elses content, sorry for the mess.

Comment: By the way, the problem is here: `if ((taxiList.get(i).getPhone())==phone)`. String comparison should be done using `equals`, not `==`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He said in comments he is using real request for testing, not the Spring ones. Comparing with == is yet another issue.

Comment: The request may contain `+` but it will be parsed as `%2B` that will be handled by Spring to be converted back to `+`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please stop, i already deploy my app with EQUALS. and problem in sign "+"

Comment: @mechanikos did you try /getTaxiByPhone?phone=%2B73812999997

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please delete "duplicate" mark. this issue is rarely and intresting and not about comparing strings

Comment: @Niemand just now. and it`s work) thank you very much, i hope that my problem will be help for others

Comment: @mechanikos edit your question properly (updating code and providing necessary data to replicate the problem) and I'll remove the vote to close.